# Java, class member or method-local variable: which one is better for performance?

Tags: java, class, methods, reference

I wondered the difference between class member variable and method-local variable for performance. Here the explaining;

This is for class member variable;

```
    public class Foo{
      static String ref;
      public static void union(String a, String b){
       ref= a+b;
       }
    }
```

And this is for method-local variable;

```
      public class Foo{

      public static void union(String a, String b){
       String ref= a+b;
       }
    }
```

Suppose I call this function oftenly, in second example does the JVM create every time the ref reference(if so should I write like first example?)  or JVM create a once and use it always?

Comment: Your first exemple won't compile: you can't access an instance field from a static context. You should remove the `static` method modifier.

Comment: Sorry I edited. I forgot to write static keyword
@tt_emrah

Comment: Don't worry about what's most efficient, worry about what's _right_ and trust Java to do the right thing.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman Yes you are right, just curiosity :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to distinguish between two things here:

- variables
- objects

In both of your cases, a new `String` object for the expression `a + b` is created.

When you use a class field for storing the result, the same memory is used every time. The memory is somewhere in the heap. But: if you call that method from multiple threads at the same time, they will all use the very same memory for storing their result, and they will overwrite it. This means that one thread might see the result of a different thread, which is bad.

When you use a local variable, new memory is used for every method call. But this is *local* memory on the call stack, which practically doesn’t cost anything. Plus, you can call your method from multiple threads at the same time.

Therefore, you should use the second snippet.

Comment: Actually,usage depends on the context. You can't decide which one is better unless the condition on which it is  going to be implemented is known! Both of them have their own purpose/usage. What if Class field is to be compared for multiple objects of same class?

Comment: Every time I call method with different parameters, JVM create a new object and linked with ref, right? Does it differ which I choose of them?

Comment: Yes, it differs. In your second example, you cannot access `ref` anymore after the method `union` has been executed. In your first example, you can still access the result by writing `Foo.ref`.

Comment: Yes I know it, but I just wonder the performance differs. In Second example, I know JVM creates a reference in stack evey method calling. Is it right and does it performance cost?

Comment: Practically, local variables don’t cost anything. They may be even cheaper than class member fields, since the Java optimizer may eliminate them completely in some situations. With class member fields, this is often not possible.

Answer (score 1):

`Class fields` will be available from multiple methods from within the class whereas `local variables` are only accessible from within the method. You would use `Class fields` only if they really the attribute of a class else keep them local.